# Unable to add text input to li

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to add text entered in an  field  to the end of a list using Jquery . This is my HTML .

```js
    $(function() {
    
    
    var $newitem = $('#newItemButton');
    var $text = $('#itemDescription');
    
    $newitem.show();
    $('#newItemForm').hide();
    $('#showForm').on('click', function(){
     $newitem.hide();
     $('#newItemForm').show();
    });  
    $('#addButton').on('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var text = $text.val();
     console.log(text);   //Why is this not working 
     $('li:last').after('<li>'+ text +'</li>');
     $newItemForm.hide();
        $newitem.show();
        
    });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>JavaScript </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/c07.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="page">
          <h1 id="header">List</h1>
          <h2>Buy groceries</h2>
          <ul>
            <li id="one" class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
            <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
            <li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
            <li id="four">balsamic vinegar</li>
          </ul>
          <div id="newItemButton"><button href="#" id="showForm">new item</button></div>
          <form id="newItemForm">
            <input type="text" id="itemDescription" placeholder="Add description..." />
            <input type="submit" id="addButton" value="add" />
          </form>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script src="show.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

While other things are working the user input is not getting added to the end of the li . I tried console logging the user input value but nothing is showing up . Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Also could someone let me know how do they debug Jquery efficiently ? I tried to trace in chrome inspector but it goes to the Jquery file unlike when using vanilla JS and tracking the program execution and variable assignment seems to be all most impossible with so much Jquery code being run .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
$(function() {
    var $newitem = $('#newItemButton');
    var $text = $('#itemDescription');

    $newitem.show();
    $('#newItemForm').hide();
    $('#showForm').on('click', function(){
        $newitem.hide();
        $('#newItemForm').show();
    });

    $('#addButton').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $text.val();
        console.log(text);
        $('li:last').after('<li>'+ text +'</li>');
        $newItemForm.hide();
        $newitem.show();

    });
});
```

You should be using `click`, not `submit`.

### How to debug JavaScript / jQuery

Your `console.log` approach is not bad. Since you've noticed it doesn't get executed, you should ask yourself, *why* it is not getting executed. In this case it was the wrong listener tag (`submit` instead of `click`).

Another approach is, as you've mentioned, to use the Chrome debugger. You can set a breakpoint by clicking on a line number. This way you skip all irrelevant code.

[image: Chrome debugger with breakpoint]

Also you should probably always also use "Step over" (or <kbd>F10</kbd>) to go forward in debug mode, to not unnecessarily see the jQuery code.

[image: Step Over or F10]

Comment: The book I am learning from says $(function() { } ) is a shorthand of $(document).ready(function() { } . Is this a bad practice ? If yes why ?

Comment: @Knownow I am sorry, my bad. It looks like you are right.

Answer (score 3):

`e.preventDefault` will prevent the current behavior. Look at your code.

```
 $('#addButton').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
```

You have added the `preventDefault`, which means you are not preventing the submission of the form. This code should changed to

```
$('#newItemForm').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
```

Now whenever the form is trying to submit you are preventing it. This should work as you expected. Look at the snippet below.

```js
$(function() {

var $newitem = $('#newItemButton');
var $text = $('#itemDescription');

$newitem.show();
$('#newItemForm').hide();
$('#showForm').on('click', function(){
    $newitem.hide();
    $('#newItemForm').show();
});  
$('#newItemForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $text.val();
    console.log(text);   //Why is this not working 
    $('li:last').after('<li>'+ text +'</li>');
    $('#newItemForm').hide();
    $newitem.show();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
      <h1 id="header">List</h1>
      <h2>Buy groceries</h2>
      <ul>
        <li id="one" class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
        <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
        <li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
        <li id="four">balsamic vinegar</li>
      </ul>
      <div id="newItemButton"><button href="#" id="showForm">new item</button></div>
      <form id="newItemForm">
        <input type="text" id="itemDescription" placeholder="Add description..." />
        <input type="submit" id="addButton" value="add" />
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
    
    
    var $newitem = $('#newItemButton');
    var $text = $('#itemDescription');
    
    $newitem.show();
    $('#newItemForm').hide();
    $('#showForm').on('click', function(){
     $newitem.hide();
     $('#newItemForm').show();
    });  
    $('#addButton').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var text = $text.val();
     $('ul').append('<li>'+ text +'</li>');
     $('#newItemForm').hide();
      $newitem.show();
      $text.val('');
    });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>JavaScript </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/c07.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="page">
          <h1 id="header">List</h1>
          <h2>Buy groceries</h2>
          <ul>
            <li id="one" class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
            <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
            <li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
            <li id="four">balsamic vinegar</li>
          </ul>
          <div id="newItemButton"><button href="#" id="showForm">new item</button></div>
          <form id="newItemForm">
            <input type="text" id="itemDescription" placeholder="Add description..." />
            <input type="submit" id="addButton" value="add" />
          </form>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script src="show.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated javascript that works:

```
$(function() {
    var $newitem = $('#newItemButton');
    var $text = $('#itemDescription');

    $newitem.show();
    $('#newItemForm').hide();
    $('#showForm').on('click', function(){
        $newitem.hide();
        $('#newItemForm').show();
    });  
    $('#newItemForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $('#itemDescription').val();
        console.log(text);   //Why is this not working 
        $('li:last').after('<li>'+ text +'</li>');
        $('#newItemForm').hide();
        $newitem.show();
    });
});
```

**More explanations**

The `submit` event must be binded on a `form` element. See JQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

In your code, you misuse the `$()` function. It should take a selector as parameter. Basically, you can use the `id` of the element.